# Запустить приложение из книги Хортсмана

Tags: java, swing

Я только начал изучать язык и столкнулся с проблемой при создании swing приложения.
Вот сам код, как его запустить я не знаю (: Насолько я понимаю не хватает интерфейса Runnable и метода run. Но в это примере отсутствует Jframe, так что я затруднении. Спасибо.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel{

    private JButton display;
    private JPanel panel;
    private double result;
    private String lastCommand;
    private boolean start;

    public CalculatorPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        result = 0;
        lastCommand = "=";
        start = true;

        display = new JButton("0");
        display.setEnabled(false);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ActionListener insert = new InsertAction();
        ActionListener command = new CommandAction();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        addButton("7", insert);
        addButton("8", insert);
        addButton("9", insert);
        addButton("/", command);

        addButton("4", insert);
        addButton("5", insert);
        addButton("6", insert);
        addButton("*", command);

        addButton("1", insert);
        addButton("2", insert);
        addButton("3", insert);
        addButton("-", command);

        addButton("0", insert);
        addButton(".", insert);
        addButton("=", command);
        addButton("+", command);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    private void addButton (String label, ActionListener listener) {

        JButton button = new JButton(label);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        panel.add(button);
    }

    private class InsertAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String input = event.getActionCommand();
            if (start) {

                display.setText("");
                start = false;
            }
            display.setText(display.getText() + input);
        }
    }

    private class CommandAction implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String command = event.getActionCommand();

            if (start) {
                if (command.equals("-")) {

                    display.setText(command);
                    start = false;
                } else lastCommand = command;
            } else {

                calculate(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
                lastCommand = command;
                start = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void calculate (double x) {

        switch (lastCommand) {
            case "-":
                result -= x;
                break;
            case "+":
                result += x;
                break;
            case "/":
                result /= x;
                break;
            case "*":
                result *= x;
                break;
            case "=":
                result = x;
                break;
        }

        display.setText("" + result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Насолько я понимаю не хватает интерфейса Runnable и метода run. Но в это примере отсутствует Jframe

вроде бы не связные вещи, но тебе виднее, вообще не хватает метода main

Comment: Ну я понимаю что отсутствует main, я просто не могу понять как его вставить в приложение. Это пример 1 к 1 из книги Хортсмана 1ый том. Можен он забыл добавить что то, я сам плохо понимаю.

Comment: @Remind, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А попробуйте прям перед описанием конструктора (под переменными) вставьте:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{ new CalculatorPanel(); }
```

Comment: теперь Idea видит приложение, и запускается, но всё равно ничего не происходит. После пары секунд обдумываний, он закрывает приложение и выходит без ошибок. Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Сразу скажу, со swing не знаком, но судя по [примеру](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE/VoronCalc.java) Вам все же понадобится класс, производный от JFrame, в который надо добавить Вашу `CalculatorPanel`, а затем в `main` надо сделать этот (производный от JFrame) объект видимым.

--

Т.е. как я понимаю, к main-loop swing-а (эта штука д.б. спрятана где-то внутри JFrame) сейчас ничего вообще не подключено, он просто не может найти объекты, события которых надо обрабатывать.

Comment: О спасибо большое. Действительно стоило немного подумать как добавить
JFrame. В итоге до класса CalculatorPanel, добавил класс CalculatorFrame, расширяющий класс JFrame.

class CalculatorFrame extends JFrame {
    CalculatorFrame() {

        add(new CalculatorPanel());
        pack();

    }
}

Далее отдельно сделал класс с методом main, добавив поток диспетчиризации событий
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... }

Всем спасибо